# Regex to match string after last space and before a square bracket

Tags: regex, perl

I have some text following the pattern bellow:

> Some text with many spaces[some text inside square brackets].

I wanted a regular expression that matches the word after the last space character, and before the opening square bracket. In this example, it would be 'spaces'.

After trying this regex **.*\s(.*)\[** on this [online tester](https://regex101.com/r/9wsmd3/1/), I gave it a try using a Perl inline

```
$ cat file-containing-pattern.txt | perl -ne "print $1 if s/.*\s(.*)(\[)/\1/"
```

but it prints:

> spacessome text inside square brackets].

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: This is a shell problem. Use `'...'` around your code, not `"..."`.

Comment: @melpomene, this is really a thing. I have totally forgotten this could mess with the command. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting match and replace confused. the match is right and you repalce with with capture group one. however, you do not replace the text after and including group 2 "([)".

you either want to match and print

```
cat file-containing-pattern.txt | perl -ne 'm/.*\s(.*)\[/ and print $1;'
```

or you can replace everything but the match

```
 cat file-containing-pattern.txt | perl -pe 's/.*\s(.*)\[.*/$1/;'
```

Comment: yep, you're right. im missing single quotes. missed that. corrected

Comment: the first command you posted worked well. The later one did not. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Four issues:

- You are misquoting the command, causing the shell to interpolate `$1`.
- You are using `\1` outside of a regular expression, which makes no sense.
- You are using a substitution when it makes no sense to do so.
- You rely on Perl internals to find the correct match rather than using an accurate pattern.

Fix:

```
perl -nle'print $1 if / \s ( [^\s\[]+ ) \[ /x' file
```

Comment: Yeah, as @melpomene stated, the misquoting was really an issue. But the `\1` is used to replace the matched group with the same text. That was just a workaround for not knowing the `m//` command. And your command does not work.

Comment: @HiagoPrata No, if you want to refer to the matched text, use `$1`, not `\1`.

Comment: @HiagoPrata There was a typo in the pattern. I changed `\S` to `\s` and now it works.

Comment: Thanks @melpomene